# How to interpret highly imbalanced importance weights from vw-varinfo

Tags: vowpalwabbit

Vowpal is a great tool and we use it all the time. One thing that I've routinely run into when training models on rare event binomial data is that the output of `vw-varinfo` seems to be highly imbalance. Here's an example of what I mean, the first few lines of output from the Kaggle Springleaf competition data set:

```
FeatureName                        HashVal   MinVal   MaxVal    Weight   RelScore
num^VAR_0241_trans                  219348     0.00     0.00 +128.7630    100.00%
cat^VAR_1934_1                       82340     0.00     1.00   +0.1997      0.16%
cat^VAR_0232_2                       24324     0.00     1.00   +0.1418      0.11%
cat^VAR_0005_0                       43252     0.00     1.00   +0.1085      0.08%
bin^VAR_0550_bin1                    85964     0.00     1.00   +0.0902      0.07%
```

This suggests that `VAR_0241` pretty much contains all the signal in the data and that every other feature is irrelevant. But this is at odds with the importance results that we're seeing from our GBMs and RFs. Anyone out there more familiar then I who might have a guess about what's going on? Posting sample data wasn't practical, but the code being used to run this is:

```
vw-varinfo -c --nn 5 -f nnet.vw --passes 20 -l 0.26 --loss_function logistic -d train.vw > /tmp/vw_info_nn.txt
```

Comment: I wrote the original `vw-varinfo`.  It happened before `--nn` was supported. I suspect the output from `vw-varinfo` is incorrect in this case.  Note the (senseless) Min/Max val range for the top weighted feature.  It has been on my todo list to fix it so it is more robust and agnostic to new options. Just didn't get to it yet. Sorry.

Comment: Good to know, and no need to apologize!! This is amazing software. Thanks for sharing with the community.